# How can I get more detail in pdf file that created by core plot?

Tags: core-plot, scatter-plot

I use core plot to create ECG graph. I can see the detail in the ECG graph in my app, but I can't see the detail in the pdf file.

How can I get more detail in pdf file that like app screenshot?

Thanks, Midas

[image: PDF file screenshot]

[image: App screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is exported at the same size as the layer. Set the size of the layer bounds to a larger size before calling `-dataForPDFRepresentationOfLayer` or `-imageOfLayer`.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I set large size, and I get more detail in pdf file.

Comment: I've asked a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059040/how-can-i-create-a-line-graph-in-coreplot) fairly similar to this one about the basics of creating a line graph using CorePlot. Would you mind perhaps answering it?